# What is the difference between the version of ruby installed with Homebrew, and the one displayed with `ruby -v`?

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm on OS X, and I installed Ruby using `brew install ruby`.

I noticed the following things:

1. When I looked at ruby-lang.org, it indicated that the latest version was 2.7.0. When I ran `brew upgrade ruby` a second time, it said "Warning: ruby 2.6.5 already installed". Does this mean that 2.6.5 is the latest stable version? I didn't see any indication of this on ruby-lang.org.
2. When I ran `ruby -v`, it returned

   ```
   ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
   ```

   Why does this version seem not to have been upgraded to 2.6.5? Is the version returned by `ruby -v` the OS X system version, as opposed to the Homebrew version? If so is there a way to know which will be used when I run Ruby commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that Ruby 2.7 is so new that your brew is not updated to know about it.

You need to configure your shell to use the Ruby that brew installed. To do so, edit your shell profile to put brew’s Ruby ahead of the built-in Ruby in the `PATH` order. See any online tutorial such as "[How To Install Ruby and Set Up a Local Programming Environment on macOS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos)" for details.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'd put the lines in my shell profile before, but I hadn't entered `source ~/.bash_profile` or restarted my Terminal (not sure if the second part was necessary or not), but now `ruby -v` returns version 2.6.5.

Comment: About the first part though, I did `brew update`, and it still just gets 2.6.5 instead of 2.7. Could it be that 2.7 is so new that even the newest version of brew doesn't know about it?

Comment: It takes the Homebrew maintainers time to modify their scripts; They don't want to have the code automatically grab a new version and then let it be installed by users if the code is not stable or has somehow been hacked. There'd be a lot of upset people. The same occurs with any Linux distribution too; It takes a little while for them to jump on board. Sandboxes, like rbenv and RVM tend to move more quickly in my experience. I prefer the simplicity of the first but YMMV.

Comment: @RNdev: In many parts of the world, the time between middle/end of December and middle of January is a time with multiple holidays. New Ruby versions are traditionally released on December, 25th; this was also true of Ruby 2.7. So, chances are that whoever maintains the Homebrew Formula for Ruby simply hasn't been back to work since December, 25th. For example, at my employer, the first day of work for many people was just yesterday, and many people will only return on the 13th. That week then, is traditionally a week where all employees from all over the world come to HQ for meetings, so …

Comment: "*actual*" work will only commence on the 20th. I guess similar things are true for pretty much any country with a predominantly Christian tradition. (Note that in some communities, Christmas is celebrated *this week* because that's when the Wise Men brought their presents.)